# Minecraft Datapack drop X blocks instead of One when Destroying any block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I want to create a Datapack.
My goal is to **drop more than one** items when destroying a block in Minecraft.

For example:
When I destroy a grass-block it drops default One dirt-block. But I want (for example) 10 dirt blocks get dropped when I destroy a grass block.

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What did you try yourself so far? It should be pretty straightforward with a block loot table, that feature was explicitly added for exactly that.

Comment: @FabianRöling Thank you for your answer! I tried to create a loot table for the grass-block in /data/loot_tables/blocks/grass_block.json and there i changed the rolls option to 2 instead of one. But this didnt worked

Comment: @FabianRöling maybe you could show me how to create a block loot table? Because I dont know how to do it

Comment: Then you should ask about your specific loot table problem instead, with as much detail as possible. Also, that was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @FabianRöling nope. Because my problem wasnt only the loot table itsself. My problem was generally how to create one and where to place it in the datapack-folder. That's why I didnt show a code snippet.

Comment: In general, you should always give as much information as possible in these questions. And you should research yourself first, for example the wiki gives you all the information you need, at least in theory. Then you can ask about specifics if you don't understand the wiki or a specific step doesn't work. Log files are also always helpful.

Comment: @FabianRöling yes I researched myself of course before I asked this question. So on actually every website the file-structure of the data-packet is different and the commands also. Thats why i got confused because datapacks havent a uniform file-structure. Also in the wiki isnt written down where to place my json files and what to put in to drop items for one block. There arent really examples for this sitiuation anywhere

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_pack#Folder_structure

Comment: Side question, wouldn’t this lead to duplication as you can place something, then break it, then repeat?

Comment: @FabianRöling yes i know this page. But this page isnt helpfull to show where to place my file for solving my problem.

Comment: @brododragon nope because you destroy a grass block and get dirt back. My function sould only work in this example for grass blocks

Comment: I linked you exactly to the section where they show the tree graph of datapacks!

Comment: @FabianRöling thanks for your help. But you know my problem, why you cant add an Answer to my Question?

Comment: @FabianRöling you know what I want to do. These wiki pages dont really help me because they are unclear so the easiest thing you could do is creating an answer

Comment: It's not the easiest thing, because I'm not on a computer running Minecraft. This page actually lists exactly all the files you can put into a datapack: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Resource_pack#Folder_structure Yes, I know it says "resource pack", but if you use browser search for "data", you should get there on the 8th result. Warning: Don't try on a phone, it froze my browser for multiple minutes.

Comment: @FabianRöling Okay thank you thats actually more helpful than the other wiki pages. But now I know the folder structure. But I still dont know WHERE to edit the file and WHAT CODE to put in the file to get it work. So I tried the one answer at the bottom of the page but this didtn worked for me

Comment: Try an example datapack, for example the one in Vanilla, and modify it. Otherwise I already told you all my datapack knowledge that's not in the wiki.

Comment: @FabianRöling a good example is the answer below from cherryblossom. He used a path for this grass_block.json which doesnt exists in the Folder Structure from the wiki. How does he know this path when it doesnt exists in the wiki?

Comment: I suspect that he doesn't know, he just guessed and probably guessed wrongly. Alright, you convinced me. ;) I'll try to figure this out myself this evening, by extracting the default loot tables from the version .jar.

Comment: @FabianRöling his solution worked for me even when he uses a path which isnt described in the wiki. Thats what i meant, the wiki is really useless because only a path which isnt declared in the wiki solved my problem :) I am happy now that it finally works! You can try the solution below out when you dont belive :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loot tables. For your example, save this as `data_pack_name/data/minecraft/loot_tables/blocks/grass_block.json`.

```
{
  "type": "block",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "dirt",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "set_count",
              "count": 10
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, that would also remove the ability to get a grass block using Silk Touch.

For more detailed information, see [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table).

Comment: Thank you verry much! I will try it out and when it works i will accept your answer :)

Comment: I tried your solution but it didnt worked :( So did you tried your own?

Comment: I destroyed grass blocks but didnt get back 10 blocks of dirt. Maybe when you get it working at you, could you send me the datapack?

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry, I forgot the `blocks` folder in `loot_tables`. I updated the file name in my answer. Try that and see if that works.

Comment: thx, I will try it out :)

Comment: Thank you really much! Your solution worked!! :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I'm not an expert in datapacks at all, but just from looking at the wiki and the Vanilla loot tables I've created a datapack that works.

Folder structure:

```
saves
└<world_name>
 └datapacks
  └<datapack_name>
   ├pack.mcmeta
   └data
    └minecraft
     └loot_tables
      └blocks
       └grass_block.json
```

Contents of `pack.mcmeta`:

```
{"pack":{"pack_format":3,"description":""}}
```

Contents of `grass_block.json`:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:block",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:alternatives",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "minecraft:item",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:match_tool",
                  "predicate": {
                    "enchantments": [
                      {
                        "enchantment": "minecraft:silk_touch",
                        "levels": {
                          "min": 1
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "name": "minecraft:grass_block"
            },
            {
              "type": "minecraft:item",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:survives_explosion"
                }
              ],
              "name": "minecraft:dirt",
              "functions":[
                {
                    "function": "minecraft:set_count",
                    "count": {
                        "min": 10.0,
                        "max": 10.0
                    }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is likely way more than you actually need, but it works. Going from there you can experiment with leaving stuff out and seeing what breaks it or not. (And please tell me then!)

Comment: Thank you that you took time to find a solution! I will try it out when I will be at home this evening :)